# Unable to Delete Email Messages in Thunderbird

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, email

In Thunderbird 24.0.0 I am unable to delete emails using any of the following methods:

- Delete key
- Right click, Delete Message
- Right click, Move To -> Trash
- Manually dragging a message to the trash

Everything else seems to work fine.

I don't see any kind of error message, it just does nothing.

This is a clean install, I did not move or import any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue.

I started Thunderbird from the command line and noticed it was complaining about not being able to open the local message store every time I tried to delete a message.

To fix the problem I just deleted the following files:

```
~/.thunderbird/[profile_folder]/Mail/Local Folders/Trash 
~/.thunderbird/[profile_folder]/Mail/Local Folders/Trash.msf
```

When Thunderbird restarted it recreated them and delete now works.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder then delete it and empty trash.
I dont know why but it works after that :)